# The Rambam on distracting others from concentrating on their tefillos

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, rambam

I heard someone state the following:

The Rambam (Hilchos Teshuvah) says, "Those who speak and distract others from concentrating on their tefillos are guilty of the serious crime of 'hindering others from performing a mitzvah.' If one, G-d forbid disturbs his fellow man who is trying to daven, it is nearly impossible for him to forgive you for disturbing his opportunity to fulfill the mitzvah of davening to Hashem Yisborach!"

Does anyone know where the Rambam says this in Hilchos Teshuvah?

Comment: Is that a direct quote from somewhere?  If so, where?  Knowing where you heard the claim can help people in answering.

Comment: I think it came from Hilchos Teshuvah.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include what you know about it already.

Comment: @RealTorah you got this direct quotation from somewhere. Where?

Comment: For what it's worth, Hilchos Teshuva isn't that big. I would recommend simply reading through it yourself and finding it out. You can find an English translation here: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911887/jewish/Teshuvah.htm

Comment: You've apparently misunderstood my question.  That quoted block that makes up most of your question -- where did you find *that*?  You're asking us to investigate something you've seen but you're not telling us where you saw it.

Comment: The words "Hashem Yisborach" do not appear in Hilchos Teshuvah

Answer (score 2):

I have learned Hilchos Teshuva numerous times, and nowhere does the Rambam say such a thing in Hilchos Teshuva.

Comment: +1, however 4:3 and 3:10 seem to form the basis of the ideas in the OP.